# How to call IDM(Internet Download Manager) from my C# application

Tags: c#, api

- The IDM offers some API for client
  applications:http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm_api.html
- How can I do this via C#?

> ```
> #import "IDManTypeInfo.tlb" 
> #include "IDManTypeInfo.h"                
> #include "IDManTypeInfo_i.c" 
> #include <atlbase.h>     //for CComBSTR class
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     //.........
> }
> ```

Comment: That's C++, you can't really directly translate it to C#. However, you can always do some wrapper .dll in C++ and get it's functions invoked / called in C#.

Comment: Check this out [How to call IDM(Internet Download Manager) from my C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746703/how-to-add-download-links-to-idm-from-a-program/50661678#50661678)

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly easy, theoretically speaking.

IDM seems to be a COM library,
all you need to do is throw the TLB file into tlbimp and it will generate C# lib.

**How to: Create COM Wrappers**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use **tlbimp.exe** for this. In my computer there is this file:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\idmantypeinfo.tlb*

You now have to run tlbimp command to generate the specific C# library:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager>tlbimp idmantypeinfo.tlb
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 3.5.30729.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Type library imported to IDManLib.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager>
```

You now have generated **IDManLib.dll** that contains the necessary stuff.